# Can I wait for all forked processes from a command to finish?

Tags: shell, zsh, background-process, fork, wait

Suppose running FOO stars BAR in the background. How can I wait for BAR to finish in the shell? I want a solution where I don’t change the internals of FOO (though I can grudgingly change BAR’s.).

```
FOO

# Somehow wait on all forked processes of FOO

echo FOO and BAR have finished.
```

PS: The specific usecase I have in mind is waiting for the script that Aria2 runs using `—-on-download-complete` but I like to be able to solve this as generally as possible.

Comment: Why would the simple bash built-in `wait` not be suitable?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant It only waits for background jobs started by the shell (bar is started by foo.).

Comment: I read the Bash description closely, and couldn't decide if "child" implied "direct" or not. It looks like you can wait for a "process group", but that probably depends on whether anything in the chain invokes nohup.

Answer (score 0):

You can make BAR output its PID to a file; then check until the process with that PID is not running anymore. Something like this:

on BAR.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
(echo $$)>/tmp/BAR.pid
...
```

on runFOO.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# possibly remove pid from previous run:
if [ -f /tmp/BAR.pid ]; then
  rm /tmp/BAR.pid
fi

# launch FOO
./FOO.sh &

# make sure BAR has started:
while [ ! -f /tmp/BAR.pid ]; do
  sleep 1
done

# wait for BAR to finnish: 
while [ $(kill -s 0 $( cat /tmp/BAR.pid ) 2>&1 | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; do
  sleep 1;
done
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for concurrent launches of the script. One can use an environmental variable to solve this problem, but it’s not elegant. A neater solution using cgroups or sth seems more desirable to me.